# Plant is bending and getting die

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, indoors

[image]

Suddenly my plant start bending to one side 
I think the stem is weak and from weak stem it is shedding off
Will my plant can thrive again if i cut the upper bending part 
Or some other measure should i take

Answer (score 1):

Use a better potting medium.  It appears you are using soil from your garden.  Which is fine for the ground, but not for a pot.  A pot is an artificial environment.  It has different requirements.

It appears your plant is very dry.  Start by giving it some water to drink.  If you plant has any chance of survival it will start to perk up a little bit really soon.   But, not completely.

Next pot it in something that is called Potting Mix or Grow Mix.  These are the two words you are looking for.  These are soil made for plant pots.  You need to be very gentle repotting it this time of year, but it can be done.

Make sure you start with a pot with holes in the bottom. If it does not have hole, drill holes of buy a different pot.

Wash all the old soil off your plants roots.  Make sure you are supporting your plant while you are doing this.  Don't let the part bending bend anymore.

Next fill the bottom of your new pot with potting mix.  While holding your plant in place you will gently add the new soil around its roots.

Make sure you do not plant it any deeper than it is planted at this time.  Once it is planted.  Put a bamboo or metal stick in the pot as a stake.  Ask the garden centre for a stake for a potted plant.

If you can gently see if you can prop up the bent part. Do not force it.  Only move as much as the plant will easily move. If you can straighten it stake it in place.  If you can only prop it up part of the way stake it part of the way.

The side that the bend is on, should be the side opposite to sunlight.  The plant will want to stand up and grow towards the light.  Make sure its on the opposite side so it will stand up to get to the light.

This may not work. There may end up being a bend in your plant for the rest of it's life.

This may not save the plant.  So, think about how much you like the plant, before spending this money on a plant that may not survive, when you can probably buy a new plant for close to the same cost.